# Is it possible that setting a column as a primary key could turn some values in a column NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I needed to modify by a datatable by setting the id column as the PRIMARY KEY in order to work with it on a client I am developing. However, I forgot to copy/screen-cap the already existing records and now I get the feeling data is missing. Was it possible that setting a column as the primary key could've affected data in other columns?

FYI, I set the primary key by going into the design, right clicking the column, and clicking on "Set as primary key"

Comment: No, this is not possible -- well, unless you have some very arcane DDL trigger on the table.

Comment: Highly doubtful this happened if you saw no errors.  fyi Oracle does have a feature that is similar to what you describe if it is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

What 'design' tool were you using?  The only thing that would make sense would be if there were duplicate ids, but that should give an error instead of picking random rows.  The only other thing I can think of would be if you had a *foreign* key set to cascade deletes and deleted rows in the child table.

You only say you have an 'idea' that rows were deleted.  That makes me think that you might be just doing some simple 'select top(100) *' query or something and don't see the same data as you had before, i.e. you used to see ids like 2093939 and now you only see 1, 2, 3, etc.

When creating a primary key or a clustered index, that can alter the order that rows are returned by default.  Creating a clustered primary key would most likely then return the rows in ascending order in that case by default.  Could this be the case?